# issues with two version of qtcreator?

Tags: uninstall, ubuntu-sdk, make, qt-creator

I recently compiled qtcreator from the source files, but noticed i was missing some plugins, so I uninstalled by

```
sudo make uninstall
rm -rf qtcreator.dir qtcreator.tar
```

I then later found a wizard which could install it, which also installed the needed plugins..

Problem now is that it seems like i still have the old version.

The version which opens when I execute `qtcreator` from the terminal, 
is the one that  missing the plugins, and I know for fact that it is the incorrect one as

```
which qtcreator
/usr/bin/qtcreator
```

and the one i should be using is the one which opens when search for it in the  "application finder"... So how do I make those two the same?

Comment: what should `which qtcreator` have displayed for the correct one, and did you restart your system?

Comment: Run `qtchooser`